# Designing new BaseAdapter Pattern in Android

Tags: android, generics, design-patterns, abstraction, android-adapter

**UPDATED:** No more error present! Please comment on the pattern itself now. The pros and cons. What you like, what you don't. What can be fixed. Still don't understand why I did this...the let me know (but read my post below)

I have been working on creating a new design pattern for BaseAdapters in Android, and so far I am really liking how it is turning out!

---

I have a data structure that can hold all the needed data for each and every entity in a specific type of collection.  I am creating specific BaseAdapter implementations with their own UI layout to be displayed to the user on the screen. Pretty basic and great idea...nothing new.

---

**OK, so WHY do I want this?**

The general idea behind wanting to do this is 1) to abstract away the getView method implementation and to allow more amateur developers an easier time creating their own custom adapters and 2) to simplify and abstract away as much detail as possible.

NOTE: in the last 2 code pieces, I only have 3 things to implement (that make more sense). A inner class that is present in current Holder pattern used, a SetLayoutResource(...) method, and a ExtractLayoutResources(...) method.

***The 3 key reasons why I want this and think it is good are... abstraction, abstraction, abstraction!***

---

**ConcreteCustomAdapter.java**

*(Concrete example code...this is basically how all will look like!!! This is basically all that you would have to type up to create a new Custom BaseAdapter!!!)*

```
public class ConcreteCustomAdapter extends BaseDataAdapter<Song, SongHolder> {

    public ConcreteCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, Song[] data) {

        super(context, resource, data); 

        // Give the base class a reference to the actual type of Holder class to use
        this.setViewHolder(new SongHolder());

    }

    @Override
    protected void setLayoutResources(SongHolder holder, Song data) {

        // Set the View Holder objects properties with the current data
        holder.imgUiControl.setImageResource(data.thumbnail);
        holder.txtUiControl.setText(data.Name);

    }

    @Override
    protected void extractLayoutResources(View row, SongHolder holder) {


        // Convert XML UI component definitions into the static View Holder object
        holder.imgUiControl = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgUiControl);
        holder.txtUiControl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtUiControl);

    }

    // Class that holds all the UI component references
    static class SongHolder implements IHolder {

        ImageView imgUiControl;
        TextView txtUiControl;

    }

}
```

**Song.java**

*(User created!)*

```
// Entity that holds ALL the data
public class Song implements IData {

    public int thumbnail;
    public String Name;
    ...

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters
    ...
}
```

---

**THE REST OF THE CODE IS FOR SUPPORT PURPOSES**

---

**IHolder.java**

```
// Current Adapter Pattern uses Holder Objects, this represents that and the data via interface
public interface IHolder {

    interface IData { } 

}
```

**BaseDataAdapter.java**

*(User should NOT touch this)*

```
// D for Data....H for Holder (sorry not convention)
public abstract class BaseDataAdapter<D extends IData, H extends IHolder> extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceID;
    private D data[] = null;
    private H holder = null;

    public BaseDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, D[] data) {
        //super(context, resource, data);

        this.layoutResourceID = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater newView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = newView.inflate(this.layoutResourceID, parent, false);

            extractLayoutResources(row, holder);

            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (H) row.getTag();

        }

        setLayoutResources(holder, data[position]);

        return row;

    }

    public void setViewHolder(H holder) {

        this.holder = holder;

    }

    abstract protected void setLayoutResources(H holder, D data);
    abstract protected void extractLayoutResources(View row, H holder);


    @Override
    public int getCount() { return this.data.length; }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { return this.data[position]; }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return 0; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
public abstract class TypedListAdapter<T, H extends TypedListAdapter.ViewHolder> extends BaseAdapter {

  private final int itemViewId;
  private List<T> data;

  public TypedAdapter(final int itemViewId) {
    this(itemViewId, null);
  }

  public TypedAdapter(final int itemViewId, final List<T> data) {
    this.itemViewId = itemViewId;
    this.data = preventNull(data);
  }

  private List<T> preventNull(final List<T> data) {
    return data == null ? Collections.<T>emptyList() : data;
  }

  public void setData(final List<T> data) {
    final List<T> nonNullData = preventNull(data);
    if (nonNullData != this.data) {
      this.data = nonNullData;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
  }

  @Override
  public T getItem(final int position) {
    return data.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final H holder = obtainHolder(convertView, parent);
    bind(holder, getItem(position));
    return holder.view;
  }

  protected abstract void bind(final H holder, final T item);

  private H obtainHolder(final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemViewId, parent, false);
      return createHolder(view);
    } else {
      return (H) convertView.getTag();
    }
  }

  protected abstract H createHolder(final View view);

  public static class ViewHolder {
    public final View view;

    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
      this.view = view;
      view.setTag(this);
    }
  }
}
```

An implementation of the adapter could look like this:

```
public class SongListAdapter extends TypedListAdapter<Song, SongListAdapter.SongHolder> {

  public SongListAdapter(final int itemViewId) {
    super(itemViewId);
  }

  public SongListAdapter(final int itemViewId, final List<Song> data) {
    super(itemViewId, data);
  }

  @Override
  protected void bind(final SongHolder holder, final Song item) {
    holder.name.setText(item.getName());
    holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(item.getThumbnail());
  }

  @Override
  protected SongHolder createHolder(final View view) {
    return new SongHolder(view);
  }

  public static class SongHolder extends ViewHolder {

    public final ImageView thumbnail;
    public final TextView name;

    public SongHolder(final View view) {
      super(view);

      thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
      name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I have come a ways on my code, and will post an updated version of it tomorrow during the day. I would hope you can come back to but your views on it. Besides the error issue, I am looking for a super easy and intuitive way to implement custom adapters that can be connect to complex (mostly custom) layouts.........I currently have it where the user can extend the BaseDataAdapter and only implement 2 (TWO) methods, and a simple static class. No overhead, just and amateur codes can easily follow. That is the idea, and I will post my code tomorrow

Comment: With my solution you also only need to override two methods - very similar to your solution. createHolder() takes View and connects it to a ViewHolder. Of course there must be a custom implementation of ViewHolder. In bind() you bind your data object to the views of the ViewHolder. I don't see the point in the IData interface in your solution. Also, I wouldn't use an array as a data source. If you do have an array, you can just wrap it with an ArrayList.

Comment: My old implementation needed `IData` interface. I have been removing a lot of vestigial code that is not needed. I will see if I don't need that anymore. The reason I had that was if I wanted to use this in another project, I just create a new entity that implements `IData` and I am set.

Comment: And yes, I would not use an array either. I did not know how to anything with custom adapters (thus my push to make this really really easy). I based my code off of an online example, and kept it because it worked, but was planning on updating that. The biggest issue I see is that any and all of your `Adapter`s will carry a lot of extra baggage. Mine are very slim.

Comment: I am just looking for discussion right now. Trying to improve. Just want to make things easier for newbie developers, because lets be honest here. Chances are if you don't create custom adapters all the time, you have to look it up to understand what needs to be done. Maybe not you???

Comment: I will go over your `TypedListAdapter` class. It just looked very complex and foreign from what I have seen dealing with custom adapters. I will say that the implementation seems really nice though!

Comment: I've been developing for Android for quite a long time now and I get your point. Many things you have to do to get to the goal are like: .....WHAT?!? And adapters are one of these things. I've built a lot of adapters all for myself and as I already said we've obviously come to the same resolution: Implementing an Adapter is mostly the same except for the abstract stuff in our adapters. I just wanted to show you my (similar) solution because IMHO it is slightly more sophisticated.

Comment: haha yes...your solution is definitely more robust. I am interesting to see if I can take in some of your ideas and merge them in with mine. I definitely realized the public member access in the Holder class isn't really all that good.

Comment: Just 2 questions. Why are all parameters marked final. What is the benefit? Also it seems like your `createHolder(...)` and my `extractLayoutResources(...)` are similar, but you moved what I did in the Holder class. Do you see anyway of moving the implementation of your `createHolder` method to the base class? Basically, I am looking at a way to get rid of my `extractLayoutResources` and move it to the Holder like you, but just handle that stuff in the base class

Comment: I try to declare anything final that should not be changed. It implements the concept of immutable objects. Some say immutable members with public acces are better than getters. I think at least for the ViewHolder pattern this is true. If you do use final members, you must initialize them in the constructor. That's why I think it's a clean place to do all the calls to findViewById(). You can eliminate createHolder() if you eliminate the generic parameter H, but then you have to cast it in bind() and you still need to create it _somewhere_.

Answer (score 1):

About the error on your method SetLayoutResource, you've forgotten to cast the IHolder.

```
 @Override
protected void SetLayoutResource(IHolder holder, int position) {

    Song currentSong = data[position];

    // ERRORS HERE: imgSongThumbnail and company cannot be resolved, or is not a field (in IHolder!)
    holder.imgSongThumbnail.setImageResource(currentSong.thumbnail);
    holder.txtSongName.setText(currentSong.Name);
    ....

}
```

Should be

```
 @Override
protected void SetLayoutResource(IHolder holder, int position) {

    Song currentSong = data[position];
    SongHolder songHolder = (IHolder) holder;
    // ERRORS HERE: imgSongThumbnail and company cannot be resolved, or is not a field (in IHolder!)
    songHolder.imgSongThumbnail.setImageResource(currentSong.thumbnail);
    songHolder.txtSongName.setText(currentSong.Name);
    ....

}
```

You can download a working example in the following link
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5bbdw1x2IDET1YxZE4wdnpxZnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, this is the solution as to why I was getting the compile-time issues. I have done a little more work here and there, and basically this code works as expected. I get one row that will always change the data in it when scrolling. Other than that, the code works.

Comment: I would still like comments on the general pattern used. I think it is very clean and easier to use. I mean look at the concrete adapter classes. They deal with only what you care about, and nothing else. Very clean

Answer (score 1):

At first some general comments:

- Method names should begin with a lower case letter.
- Personally I would recommend renaming your generic types for better understanding. For `T` I would go with `TData` and for `V` I would use something like `VHolder`

Now for the answer:

Since you are using generics, you should also use them in the method signatures:

```
abstract protected void setLayoutResource(THolder holder, int position);
abstract protected THolder extractLayoutResources(ViewGroup parent, View row, THolder holder);
```

You now end up with this in your `GeneralSongListAdapter`

```
@Override
protected SongHolder ExtractLayoutResources(ViewGroup parent, View row,
    SongHolder holder) {
```

Now you should be able to access the fields directly without casting.

Furthermore I would recommend renaming your abstract methods. I don't think their current names say correctly what the method should do. If you look into `CursorAdapter` you see `createView` and `bindView` that do exactly what you are doing.
Perhaps use this naming.

Comment: I updated my post while you were typing this up. Some of your points are actually in the new code. The end result is MUCH cleaner, and I think much easier to code and create new Adapters at will. What do you think?

I agree the method names might not be the best. But I would argue that using the `CursorAdapter`'s naming conventions would not be any better...maybe not???